# Insight debugger crashes or hangs whe used with flyswatter2 openOCD on Beagleboard XM

Tags: linux-kernel, insight, openocd

I tried to debug linux kernel on Beagleboard XM with insight and flyswatters openOCD. After I run 
arm-linux-gnueabi-insight vmlinux, I see the kernel is downloaded to the target via jtag flyswatter2. When it is done, a message box "Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load?" is popped up. If I click "Yes", the insight would crash, otherwise it hangs,
here is from gdb window

```
0x40200fa0 in ?? ()
Loading section .note.gnu.build-id, size 0x24 lma 0x0
Loading section .init, size 0x2bc96 lma 0x80008000
Loading section .text, size 0x5c6a88 lma 0x80034000
Loading section .rodata, size 0x847 lma 0x805fb000
Loading section .builtin_fw, size 0x30 lma 0x805fb848
Loading section __ksymtab, size 0x6310 lma 0x805fb878
Loading section __ksymtab_gpl, size 0x3818 lma 0x80601b88
Loading section __kcrctab, size 0x3188 lma 0x806053a0
Loading section __kcrctab_gpl, size 0x1c0c lma 0x80608528
Loading section __ksymtab_strings, size 0x1608d lma 0x8060a134
Loading section __param, size 0xe3c lma 0x806201c4
Loading section .data, size 0x4a980 lma 0x80622000
Start address 0x80008000, load size 6697150
Transfer rate: 10 KB/sec, 16021 bytes/write.

Breakpoint 3, stext () at arch/arm/kernel/head.S:79
Current language:  auto; currently asm

(gdb) n
(gdb) n
(gdb) b kernel_init
Breakpoint 4 at 0x800089c8: file init/main.c, line 312.

(gdb) cont
Continuing.
```

Comment: What version of the kernel are you building?

Comment: 2.6.32. After download, it stops at entry point at header.S. This should be used for compressed kernel. But vmlinux is uncompressed.